# tkinter math program type error

Tags: python, math, tkinter

Hi I am making a math program that works with different users and then writes there scores into a config file (.ini) but the thing is when ever I try to do this i get an error saying:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programming\Math-Bot\Math-Bot.py", line 105, in check
    config[user]['right'] = config[user]['right'] + int(1)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Here is the code that I use to decide if they got the answer right or wrong:

```
def check():
    if guess.get().lower() == str(no1 + no2):
        global ri
        answer.set('Right!')
        ri = ri + 1
        right.set(ri)
        config[user]['right'] = config[user]['right'] + int(1)
    else:
        global wa
        answer.set('Wrong, It Was ' + str(no1 + no2))
        wa = wa + 1
        wrong.set(wa)
        config[user]['wrong'] = config[user]['right'] + int(1)
```

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your code correctly, you have a configuration value that is a string **representing** a number, is that correct? If so, you should first parse it into an `int` (as iCodez suggested), then add it, and finally format it into a string again:

```
config[user]['right'] = str( int(config[user]['right']) + 1 )
```

That's necessary because Python is a strongly typed language: most of the time, it doesn't allow operations between different types (in this case, `int` and `str`), requiring the programmer to explicitly convert one to another before applying the usual operators.

Comment: Like the one above the error stops showing up but the config file is not getting updated

Comment: @DanielAlexander that's unrelated to your main question, and is likely a problem with some other part of your code. I'm not familiar to tkinter, what is this `config` variable, and does setting values on it automatically updates the config file? Or is that something that must be done manually? Look for that info, and if you still have doubts, either update your question or ask another one

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, `config[user]['right']` is a string.  If so, you can't add 1 to it because 1 is an integer and strings and integers cannot be added together.  The `+` operator only puts together two things of the same type.  So, if you want to add 1 to `config[user]['right']`, you have to first convert it to an integer like this:

```
int(config[user]['right']) + 1
```

or, if you want to put the character 1 on the end of `config[user]['right']`, you have to first make 1 a string like this:

```
config[user]['right'] + '1'
```

Comment: Ok now I don't get any errors but the ini file is not changing how I want it to